# Second call to angular.module causes routing to fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an site I have put together based on a tutorial I found here
http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/angularjs-in-30-minutes-angularjs-tutorial/

My app.js contains

```
angular.module('kolvir', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller("kolvirController", function($http){
    var vm = this;
    vm.searchInput = '';
    $http.jsonp (
       'https://sfcons.azure-mobile.net/api/getcons/?
        callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function (data){
        vm.cons = data;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    });
});
```

I added a controller (gallery-controller.js )and routing appears to fail. After ripping things out I determined that adding the module call causes the failure, with:

angular.module('kolvir', ['ngRoute']);

Without it works just fine. I have a second site based on twitter bootstrap that uses the same pattern and it works just fine.

I am still new enough to angular I am not even certain what I should be searching for to find and answer, but so far I have not turned up anything similar to this.

Comment: _"Without it works just fine"_, then keep it removed. The only time you need to call module is either to create a new app module, or to get a reference to one that is already made and to do that you just do not specify a second argument

Comment: Please, post the code of all the scripts. Also show the actual error.

Comment: Thank you Patrick! That is exactly the info I needed. I removed the second argument and it works correctly now. (Now the question I need to figure out  is why it works on my other site with the second argument included...but I will definitely remover it there to get rid of any unintended consequences.)